# Select Columna where columna <>0

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una consulta en SQL Server en la que necesito que me muestre solo las COLUMNAS que no tengan 0

```
SELECT Codigo, Campo, Sector, SUM(Isnull([1],0)) AS [1], SUM(Isnull([2],0)) AS [2], SUM(Isnull([3],0)) AS [3], SUM(Isnull([4],0)) AS [4], SUM(Isnull([5],0)) AS [5], SUM(Isnull([6],0)) AS [6], SUM(Isnull([7],0)) AS [7], SUM(Isnull([8],0)) AS [8], SUM(Isnull([9],0)) AS [9], SUM(Isnull([10],0)) AS [10], SUM(Isnull([11],0)) AS [11]
FROM MyTabla 
WHERE V.Codigo=00173 and V.Campo=1 and V.Sector=2 
GROUP BY Codigo, Campo, Sector, [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11]
```

la cual me arroja el siguiente resultado

```
  Codigo    Campo   Sector  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11      
  00173    1      2     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   27  64  15  17
```

El problema es que si agrego (por ejemplo) al where [1]<>0...etc, ya no me muestra ningún resultado de la fila.

Pero lo que necesito es esto:

```
 Codigo Campo   Sector  8     9   10    11      
 00173      1      2    27    64      15    17
```

Mytabla

```
Id int (pk)
Codigo varchar
Campo int 
Sector int
1 float
2 float
3 float
4 float
5 float
6 float
7 float
8 float
9 float
10 float
11 float
```

Comment: Entiendo tu pregunta pero que pasaria si digamos que en este caso como muestras tu resultado se cumple, pero para el codigo 00174 el si tiene uno en el valor [1] ahi ya no podria ser...no se si me di a explicar se puede hacer de modo que si no cumple en lo que dices entonces hagamos lo que nos pides pero si luego en el caso que te menciono resulta que el [1] si tiene datos tendrias que traertelo ahi como piensas que sea?

Comment: Bueno debería poder funcionar para todos los códigos, en mi caso esta consulta se ejecutara solo un código , un campo y un sector a la vez, espero darme a entender, si entiendo de que hablas @EdgarVazquez

Comment: Ah bueno si sera por medio de una variable que manejara el codigo entonces si, pero de lo contrario no creo, a lo que me refiero que si ejecutas tu consulta y tienes como resultado lo que muestras como esperado esta bien para el codigo 00173 ... pero que pasaria si el codigo que le sigue las columnas [1],[2], que no estuvieron presente en la otra por no tener datos en esta siguiente si deben de estar... no se si me di a explicar pero si me dices que sera por codigo, es decir que mandaras una variable para filtrar por codigo entonces si creo que se pueda.

Comment: @EdgarVazquez asi es...

Comment: Un ultimo favor para empezar con la solucion podrias brindarme el esquema de tu tabla como esta conformado para que comience saludos.

Comment: Ya lo agregue a la publicacion @EdgarVazquez gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer con CASE y construyendo dinamicamente la sentencia a ejecutar, por ejemplo para las columnas 1,2 y 3 (para el resto seria lo mismo)

```
declare @sqlCmd as varchar(500)
set @sqlCmd = 'SELECT Codigo '
    + (SELECT CASE WHEN SUM(Isnull([1],0)) > 0 THEN ', SUM(Isnull([1],0)) AS [1]' ELSE '' END AS columnainventada FROM tabla Where Codigo = 'A' GROUP By Codigo)
    + (SELECT CASE WHEN SUM(Isnull([2],0)) > 0 THEN ', SUM(Isnull([2],0)) AS [2]' ELSE '' END AS columnainventada FROM tabla Where Codigo = 'A' GROUP By Codigo)
    + (SELECT CASE WHEN SUM(Isnull([3],0)) > 0 THEN ', SUM(Isnull([3],0)) AS [3]' ELSE '' END AS columnainventada FROM tabla Where Codigo = 'A' GROUP By Codigo)
    + ' FROM tabla WHERE Codigo = ''A'' GROUP BY Codigo'
-- select @sqlCmd
execute(@sqlCmd)
```

Esto lo puedes ver funcionando [aquí](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/24f855/36/0)

Te dejo un [enlace](https://www.guru99.com/sql-server-case.html) (está en inglés) donde explican bastante casuística de los CASE, por si lo que te puse no se adapta exactamente a lo que necesitas.

Comment: Hola, el signo  > lo marca rojo como error, despues de IS

Comment: @PatricioMoracho tiene razon, me sigue mostrando las columnas con 0

Comment: @Huntzberger cual es la clave primaria de la tabla?

Comment: Un Id de tipo int autoincrement @Marc

Comment: @Huntzberger he bastante toda la respuesta, creo que es lo que buscas, añadiendo a los `WHERE` los dos campos que faltan y tal vez algún detalle más.

Comment: Y hay que tener en cuenta los comentarios que hace @PatricioMoracho, este tipo de cosas siempre es mejor trabajarlo a nivel aplicación

Answer (score 3):

Algunos aclaraciones previas:

- Lo que buscas no se puede lograr con una sentencia clásica de SQL
- Es algo que debería ser trabajado por la capa de la aplicación y no por el motor.
- Creo que no debe haber más de una o dos formas de resolverlo, y ninguna es del todo óptima para el motor de la base de datos (insisto con el punto anterior)

Dicho lo anterior, pasemos a una solución mediante una consulta dinámica, la idea básica es:

- Hacer un `UNPIVOT` para transformar las 11 columnas en 11 filas
- Determinar que columnas tienen valores <> 0 y las salvamos en una tabla temporal
- Crear una sentencia dinámica que solo considere dichas columnas

Primero el `UNPIVOT`:

```
SELECT  Codigo, Campo, Sector, colname, colvalue
    INTO #MyTabla_Unpivot
    from (
            SELECT Codigo, Campo, Sector, SUM(Isnull([1],0)) AS [1], SUM(Isnull([2],0)) AS [2], SUM(Isnull([3],0)) AS [3], SUM(Isnull([4],0)) AS [4], SUM(Isnull([5],0)) AS [5], SUM(Isnull([6],0)) AS [6], SUM(Isnull([7],0)) AS [7], SUM(Isnull([8],0)) AS [8], SUM(Isnull([9],0)) AS [9], SUM(Isnull([10],0)) AS [10], SUM(Isnull([11],0)) AS [11]
            FROM MyTabla 
            WHERE V.Codigo=00173 and V.Campo=1 and V.Sector=2 
            GROUP BY Codigo, Campo, Sector, [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11]
    ) 
    unpivot
    (
        colvalue
        for colname in ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11])
    ) U
    WHERE colvalue <> 0
```

En `#MyTabla_Unpivot` tendremos una salida similar a esto:

```
codigo Campo       Sector      colname colvalue
------ ----------- ----------- ------- -----------
00173  1           2           8       27
00173  1           2           9       64
00173  1           2           10      15
00173  1           2           11      17
```

Y ahora creamos la sentencia dinámica:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT  @sql = 'SELECT Codigo, Campo, Sector'
SELECT  @sql = @sql + ',[' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, colname) + ']'
    FROM #MyTabla_Unpivot u GROUP BY colname

SELECT  @sql = @sql + char(13) + '     FROM #MyTabla'

PRINT   @sql -- Para revisar la sentencia
EXEC sp_executesql @sql -- Para ejecutarla efectivamente
```

Comentarios:

- No está de más aclarar que siempre que usas sentencias dinámicas abres la puerta en menor o mayor grado a una inyección de código, en este caso es una sentencia bastante controlada, pero no está de mas advertirlo
- Esta solución es consistente con más de una fila

Aquí un [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4dd70/4/0) con la idea de esta respuesta

Answer (score 1):

Solo complementando lo que ya se tenia pero sin consultar la tabla en todo momento o usar tablas temporales.

Esta es solo otra alternativa

```
    --Primero se declara una variable que contendra los campos a traer

    DECLARE @Fields NVARCHAR(MAX)
--creamos un CTE para traer los campos de forma dinamica
    ;WITH FormaCamposDinamicos AS(
    SELECT Codigo, Campo, Sector, 
    CASE WHEN SUM(ISNULL([1],0))=0 THEN '' ELSE '[1]' END +
    CASE WHEN SUM(Isnull([2],0))=0 THEN '' ELSE ',[2]' END +
    CASE WHEN  SUM(Isnull([3],0))=0 THEN ''ELSE ',[3]' END +
    CASE WHEN SUM(Isnull([4],0))=0 THEN '' ELSE ',[4]' END +
    CASE WHEN SUM(Isnull([5],0))=0 THEN '' ELSE ',[5]' END +
    CASE WHEN SUM(Isnull([6],0))=0 THEN '' ELSE ',[6]' END +
    CASE WHEN SUM(Isnull([7],0))=0 THEN '' ELSE ',[7]' END +
    CASE WHEN SUM(Isnull([8],0))=0 THEN '' ELSE ',[8]' END +
    CASE WHEN SUM(Isnull([9],0))=0 THEN '' ELSE ',[9]' END +
    CASE WHEN SUM(Isnull([10],0))=0 THEN ''ELSE ',[10]' END +
    CASE WHEN SUM(Isnull([11],0))=0 THEN ''ELSE ',[11]' END AS Data
    FROM MyTabla V
    WHERE V.Codigo=00173 and V.Campo=1 and V.Sector=2 
    GROUP BY Codigo, Campo, Sector, [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11])
    --Al final seleccionamos el dato mas los campos
    SELECT @Fields='SELECT  Codigo, Campo, Sector'+Data+'FROM MyTabla' FROM FormaCamposDinamicos
    --al final lo ejecutamos
    EXEC (@Fields)
```

El codigo se puede ver aqui
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6a796/3

Saludos